# Is it possible to get cell text from a remote applications StatusBarWndClass?

Tags: c#, vb6, screen-scraping

I have a legacy vb application that has data in a status bar I want to use to drive a .NET application.

I have used spy++ to gain some insight into the window structure and have successfully used FindWindow and FindWindowEx to get handles to the StatusBarWndClass. Now I am struggling to get access to the actual data in the status bar. I have tried using a WM_GETTEXT message but no success.

1. Is it possible to get cell information from the remote StatusBarWndClass?
2. How do I do it if its possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try the SB_GETTEXT message. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760749(VS.85).asp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760749(VS.85).aspx)